# Set property in Style trigger based on child property change (wpf)

Tags: wpf

I would like to achieve something in wpf which not seems to be easy to me.
I want to change the outer border's `CornerRadius` depending on the inner element's state. If the `ToggleButton`'s `IsChecked` property is `true` then change the CornerRadius of the outer element something different than the default one.

I tried - among a lot of other things - this:

```
<Border x:Name="rootElement"
      CornerRadius="5">
      <ToggleButton
          x:Name="showAdditionalOptions">
          ...
      </ToggleButton>
    <Border.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
          <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=showAdditionalOptions}" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0"/>
              </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
     </Border.Style>
 </Border>
```

I want to change the CornerRadius of rootElements if IsChecked is true for showAdditionalOptions.
I tried setting the trigger in the ToggleButtons Triggers parts (both Style.Triggers AND Template.Triggers) but from there I can't reach outer elements (TargetName does not work).

Answer (score 0):

I found out what is the problem, but I don't delete the question because trickier than it seems.
The trigger works well. When I changed the Visibility of the same item (rootElement) to collapsed then it really collapsed.
It turned out that the following line overwrites every trigger action:

```
CornerRadius="5"
```

Since it is set to 5 (5,5,5,5) nothing happened after the trigger finished running.
Instead of setting the CornerRadius on the very object, the following code shall be used:

```
<Border x:Name="rootElement">
    <ToggleButton
        x:Name="showAdditionalOptions">
        ...
    </ToggleButton>
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <!-- Set default CornerRadius here! -->
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=showAdditionalOptions}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```